# what is the theoretical solution to Voronoi domain distribution for 2D random point sets

Tags: tessellations

Consider a large set of random points in 2D plane generated by Poisson process. And consider only the finite Voronoi domains generated using these points. Is there a theoretical solution to the Voronois domain distribution if the size of the points are 5$\mu m$?

Comment: What are random points in 2D? What is the Voronoi domain distribution?

Comment: I mean randomly putting points in a plane. And I could generate the [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). And I can calculate the size of each Voronoi cell and form a histgram.

Comment: What does it mean to randomly put points in a plane? Are you thinking of a Poisson process? The question says nothing about the sizes of Voronoi cells. Please clarify the question itself; it should be possible to understand the question without reading the comments.